# Speaking in circles

Tags: visual, anagram

[image: circles]

Find a two-word phrase from these circles.

Comment: Hmmm. Circle, Ven Diagram, more Ven diagram, Audi, Olympics.

Comment: @cbronson: On the right track and 4/5 correct.  ;)  Consider converting it to an answer.

Comment: #3 is John Bonham :)

Comment: Would the [tag:rebus] tag apply? Or only of the others?

Comment: I updated the second set of circles a bit.  @BmyGuest: Perhaps the rebus tag applies, although not in its strictest interpretation, as there is one small additional step between the associated words and the final answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Vocal Chords

Each picture represents

> **C**ircle 
>  **L**ink (as suggested by ruudvan) 
>  **V**enn diagram 
>  **A**udi 
>  **O**lympics 
>  Then take the first letters and rearrange to get **VOCAL**. As pointed out by others, each circle has a chord, giving overall 'vocal chords'.

Comment: The answer is correct!  Can you think of a more general word for the second one ("Love" is a perhaps adding a bit too much meaning to it)?

Comment: L is probably Link, as in, links in a chain.

Answer (score 15):

I think it's

> Chord Progression

Comment: Good answer - given the ordering in the image; but it's not the one I intended (I wasn't aware of this phrase). Each set of circles means something specific.